# clojure data.xml force evaluate lazy xml tree

Tags: clojure

According to the README of [data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml), the data structure returned by `parse` contains lazy sequences. So the XML tree returned by

```
(with-open [r (io/input-stream (io/file "data.xml"))]
  (xml/parse r))
```

may throw an exception when traversing the tree outside this code block, because the input-stream has been already closed.

What is the most elegant way to force evaluation of the whole tree before returning? I tried the following but I am wondering if there is anything simpler.

```
(with-open [r (io/input-stream (io/file "data.xml"))]
  (doto (xml/parse r)
    (->> (tree-seq map? :content) (dorun))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `doall` to force realisation of lazy sequences, then retain just the first element. Also, you could use `xml-seq` rather than `tree-seq`:

```clj
(with-open [r (io/input-stream (io/file "data.xml"))]
  (-> r xml/parse xml-seq doall first))
```

Comment: this version keeps the whole unused sequence in the memory until the function is returned.

Comment: This is a necessary cost of non-lazy sequences. Note the sequence shares its data structure with the desired tree, so the cost may not be that high. You will need to measure the costs in your application. If the memory costs are too high, you'd need to change strategy and embrace laziness rather than seek to avoid it.

Comment: @erdos If you want to participate of the laziness, you have to move the work
inside your `with-open`.

Answer (score -1):

For general XML parsing, I might suggest [looking at tupelo.parse.xml](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.04.13/api/tupelo.parse.xml#parse).  It is not lazy, and simplifies loading of XML data.  There are similar namespaces for parsing [HTML via TagSoup](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.04.13/api/tupelo.parse.tagsoup), and also [parsing YAML](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.04.13/api/tupelo.parse.yaml).

For generic use, you can always fallback to [tupelo.core/unlazy](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.04.13/api/tupelo.core#unlazy). It will recursively walk a data structure and convert every item into a plain map, vector, set, etc. It will also realize an `InputStream` via `slurp` (very handy for testing http endpoints that return an `InputStream` instead of a string).  It also handles `java.lang.Iterable` => vector. Overall, `unlazy` is like `doall` on steroids.

---

**Aside:**

If you are wondering about the map & set stuff, it is because Datomic return values behave like a "lazy map" and do not realize all of their key-value pairs unless you specifically extract each key or dump the object into a regular Clojure map via `into` or similar.